# trouble select max value from a varchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server

SO I have an interesting issue, I have a varchar field in my table because the numbers have hyphens, so sample data looks like this...

```
tbla

Field1
102-1
20-1
56-1
```

What I'm trying to do is somehow select the MAX (highest) value from the Field1,

Desired end result.

```
Field1
102
```

the problem is I can't use a query like this...

```
Select max(field1) from tblA order by fieldA Desc
```

Because it goes off the first number of FieldA, so if i use the query above it gives me this..

```
56-1
```

When In reality I need `102-1`

Comment: Are the last 2 characters always `-1`? Or at least a `-#`

Comment: @WEI_DBA - no some numbers have "-", some don't - that's the issue. so some numbers are like 117, and some are 11-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing, you can use `top 1` and ordering by the integer part of the field descending, and the entire string descending like so:

```
select top 1
    Field1
from tbla
order by 
    convert(int,left(Field1,charindex('-',Field1+'-')-1)) desc
  , Field1 desc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BCM16018

returns:

```
+--------+
| Field1 |
+--------+
| 102-1  |
+--------+
```

In Sql Server 2012 and up: [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

Comment: erroring out on try_convert: 'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Koosh just use `convert()` if you are not on SQL Server 2012+. Are you sure you are using Sql Server 2012, and not just management studio 2012?

Comment: @Koosh Server Server 2012 (as tagged in your question) isn't the same as using management studio 2012+. Just use `convert()` instead.

Comment: sorry - i changed the tags. You got the vote. Upvote would be nice for a great question :)- can't do much without points!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(field1, 1, CHARINDEX('-',field1)-1) AS int))
```

Comment: dont work error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: try this adjustment to prevent errors for those lacking a hyphen `charindex('-',Field1+'-')`

Comment: @Koosh this is assuming all of the entries have dash

Comment: @SqlZim - that did it

Comment: not all do but found the largest one with this query